# How to get image data byte array returned from takePicture call in Android camera?

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I have a simple take picture class for an android camera application:

```
public class SimplePicture implements Picturable, PictureCallback{

    Camera camera;
    byte[] imgData; // image data in bytes


    /**
     *@param c, the camera instance that the Android phone is using.
     */
    public SimplePicture(Camera c){
        this.camera = c;

    }   

    public byte[] getPicture(int exposureCompensation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
        p.setExposureCompensation(exposureCompensation);



        if(p.getMaxExposureCompensation() > 0){  // if exposure is supported
            camera.takePicture(null, this, this);
        }


        return imgData; 


    }

    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        imgData = data; 

    }


}
```

AS you might see I am trying to have my getPicture() method to return the bytes of the image taken. Since the call back is the only function that gives me access to the imageData, I know that the callback function will be called when the image Data is ready after taking a picture. **Will the onPictureTaken function run concurrently to my getPicture
function so that the return function (return imgData) will return before setting the byte array correctly? Or does the execution wait for onPictureTaken call and then returns?**

If it was the second case, I guess my work is correct. If it was the first case, can someone lead me in the right direction. Is there a simpler way to do this or do I need to use locking to make sure my functions execute in the correct order?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to add new method outside onPictureTaken(). After image in Captured you will get byte[] from onPictureTaken() method , this is the place where you will get the Image's byte[]. So you can convert byte[] to Bitmap. Also you can use below snippet for getting byte[] of captured image

```
private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        createBitmap(data); // Some stuffs to convert byte[] to Bitmap
    }
};
```

Comment: Sorry If i was not clear in the question. I am implementing an interface that has the getPicture method which needs to return a byte array of the image data. The reason is that I am also creating other classes (more complicated) that will have the getPicture and I will get DataFlow as a result to implement some image processing algorithms...

Comment: @Saher Create you interface inside onPictureTaken() method

Comment: how will that work ? I need to define other classes like HDR and Denoise which will call the getPicture method recursively and they implement the same interface. How can I just have the interface declared inside ?